# Ruby on Rails - best_in_place sanitize option doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I am using the following code in my view:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <% if current_user == @post.user || current_user.try(:admin?) %>
        <%=best_in_place @post, :body, :as => :textarea, inner_class: 'form-control', ok_button: 'update', ok_button_class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-sm'%>
    <% else %>
        <p class="postbody"><%= sanitize @post.body %></p>
    <% end %>
    <div class="py-3">
```

Input text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Expected: #code blocks doesn't accept html tags as it seems

Lorem  **ipsum**  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Behavior

```
Lorem <b> ipsum </b> dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

If I am logged out my post.body gets sanitized.
 However, if I am logged in the text accepts html tags. (doesn't get sanitized I guess)
In the best_in_place documentation it says sanitize is set to true by default. I tried `sanitize: true` as well, still doesn't work.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Best regards

Comment: What does "(<.b>test<./b>) works (**test**)" mean? Your question is ambiguously worded, and the title doesn't match the question (I think? ... Since you're actually saying that `sanitize` works, but `best_in_place` doesn't?)

Comment: What input are you entering? (Suggestion: Write this formatted `as code` to avoid any ambiguity.) What data is being rendered in the HTML? (Suggestion: Again, write this formatted `as code` to avoid any ambiguity.) What are you expecting? What's the difference between the expectation and reality?

Comment: I tried to mention what exactly I mean. You are right. Sanitize does work, I guess you are also right about best_in_place. I'm really thinking about switching the inline-editing gem, since I have trouble doing multiple things with it. However, as the documentation states sanitize should work in the way I implemented it.

Comment: @TomLord updated my question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that the **jQuery input box, provided by `best_in_place`** does not sanitize the HTML tags? (In which case, what has this question got to do with Rails' `sanitize` method?)

Comment: Sorry if I might have asked the question the wrong way. I guess yes, that is what I mean. (Since I am logged in and I use the best_in_place method you might be correct)

Comment: This is why we ask for a [mcve] (emphasis here is on *Minimal*) on StackOverflow. If I understand correctly, your problem could be described by **one** line of code: `<%=best_in_place @post, :body, :as => :textarea %>`.

Comment: Are you saying that the `best_on_place` actually renders it in bold? Or does it render escaped text, like `&ltb&gt ipsum &lt/b&gt`? In the case of the latter, that's correct behaviour. In other words, I'm unsure what you mean by *"doesn't get sanitized I guess"*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177123/discussion-between-benl96-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an undocumented option:

```
raw: true
```

That will enable pure HTML to be rendered, without converting it to plain text before display. Someone else posted about the same problem on Github. See here:

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/520

Comment: Yes! That solved my Issue. Thank you for mentioning this!